# Wordpress php file execution

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website (buddypress plugin/themes). I'm using a plugin that requires access to a .php file in the plugins dirctory. The path is `http://localhost.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-fb-autoconnect/_process_login.php` but I'm getting the a 404 page not found error. A post on the plugins FAQs (http://www.justin-klein.com/projects/wp-fb-autoconnect) says:

> I'm getting a 404 server error while trying to execute _process_login.php.
>   Your FTP client is probably set to upload files with the wrong permissions - try changing _process_login.php and the parent directory to 755. You should be able to access _process_login.php directly and have it say "Please do not access this script directly." If not, that means your server isn't executing the php at all (and it's a problem with your server configuration rather than the plugin).

I have changed the directory permissions to 755 and I still can't access the file. I guess it's a server configuration issue.

I have no .htaccess file in the root but I'm not sure if I need to specify that a php file can be directly accessed in that or not. Can anyone suggest how I would get access to that file. I can see the directory content (just now) but can't open that file.

**Please note the site is actually live on the web but since I'm messing around with permissions I replaced the actual domain with localhost for security reasons...**

Comment: Have you check the permissions on the file itself? Set the folder + all its content to 777 and see if it works. If it does, then it's a permissions issue and you can focus on that.

Comment: Tried 777 on the parent folder and on the php file itself. Still 'page not found'

Comment: upload an html file to the same directory and see if you can access it. If you can, then rename the file to have a .php extension and see if you can access it then. If this loads as well then I'll need to see the source code for _process_login.php (I'm guessing it's failing to include a dependent file)... if you cannot load either the html file or the dummy php file, then you'll need to check your htaccess settings

Comment: Good suggestion! I created a file called test.html and was able to access it. Changed it to test.php and got page not found

Comment: OK, I'm guessing that apache (probably set via htaccess) is configured to rewrite requests to pages with .php extensions. Can you check that there are no htaccess files in your plugin folder? Also, check that you're able to access php files in other plugins.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No .htaccess file in the plugins folder. All other plugin php file have the same problem

Comment: try to see if there are any htaccess files above the plugin directory. Also, did you manage the apache configuration? If not, and you can't find anything interested in the htaccess files, you might want to have a look at the http.config file (or included config files). If you have any trouble understanding the htaccess files, put post them up here.

Comment: Nope, no .htaccess files in there. Unfortunately I don't think I've got access to http.config. I'll try asking my hosting provider if they can shed any light of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry folks my hosting provider figured it out. Somehow my wp-content directory permissions were 757. Changed them to 775 and it works. I was only changing the files direct parent directory. Thanks @Ben D for your help